# Can i use blogger conditional tags(IF) in java script

Tags: javascript, blogger

Can i use blogger conditional tags(IF) in java script

Eg:

```
<script type="javascript">
    <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;index&quot;'>
        console.log("OK");
    </b:if>
</script>
```

I have tried. Syntax error occured.

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
```

Comment: Why don't you use `<b:if...` above the `script` tag?

Comment: In my $(document).ready(function() some statements executed only if    the page type == index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use normal JavaScript `if` like below

```
if(blog.pageType==index)
  Console.log('ok');
```

**UPDATE**

Maybe you will place your code other way round like this:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;index&quot;'>
   <script type="javascript">
      console.log("OK");
      //put here only this part which should be for above condition 
   </script>
</b:if>
```

Comment: i got ReferenceError: blog is not defined

Comment: How you include blog data?

Comment: I have placed the above code after the footer section